# NotImplementedError when creating keras model with LSTM layer in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, visual-studio-2017, lstm

My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
keras_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(1000, 16),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32),
])
```

I have an error:

> NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor
> (lstm/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that
> you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported

Call stack:

```
Tensor.__array__ in ops line 848    Python  
_wrapreduction in fromnumeric line 90   Python  
prod in fromnumeric line 2962   Python  
prod in C:\Users\FA\Google Drive\Colab Notebooks\PoetryTransformer\Accentizer\<__array_function__ internals> line 6 Python  
_constant_if_small in array_ops line 2732   Python  
zeros in array_ops line 2794    Python  
wrapped in _tag_zeros_tensor in array_ops line 2747 Python  
wrapper in add_dispatch_support in dispatch line 201    Python  
create_zeros in _generate_zero_filled_state in recurrent line 2981  Python  
<listcomp> in nest line 635 Python  
map_structure in nest line 635  Python  
_generate_zero_filled_state in recurrent line 2984  Python  
_generate_zero_filled_state_for_cell in recurrent line 2968 Python  
LSTMCell.get_initial_state in recurrent line 2524   Python  
RNN.get_initial_state in recurrent line 646 Python  
RNN._process_inputs in recurrent line 862   Python  
LSTM.call in recurrent_v2 line 1108 Python  
Layer._functional_construction_call in base_layer line 1117 Python  
Layer.__call__ in base_layer line 926   Python  
RNN.__call__ in recurrent line 663  Python  
Sequential.add in sequential line 221   Python  
_method_wrapper in no_automatic_dependency_tracking in base line 457    Python  
Sequential.__init__ in sequential line 142  Python  
_method_wrapper in no_automatic_dependency_tracking in base line 457    Python  
ragged module line 5    Python
```

I can not add LSTM layer neither with Sequentional API nor with Functional API.
Custom model works well.
What could be a reason of that ?

Tensorflow version is 2.3.0.
Python version 3.6.

The error relates to Visual Studio (no error when I am running w/o VS).

Comment: Did you use np anywhere in your code? could you please share all of your code?

Comment: @Audrey This may not be related to  Visual Studio at all.

Comment: @Peyman It is the whole code

Comment: @Mohan Radhakrishnan I am not sure here. But the code works when I run it out of Visual Studio (e.g. in Colab).

Comment: I called "Repair" from Visual Studio Installer. It resolved the issue

Comment: I got into the same problem as well. It seems like the LSTM layer is not compatible with Sequential()
and it seems like a numpy thing, the error comes out when my numpy is 1.20.1. reinstalling numpy 1.19.5 fixes the issue

Comment: Downgrading numpy worked for me