# Keras SimpleRNN - why am I getting th error

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a very basic RNN model using Keras SimpleRNN in my Jupyter Labs Notebook using the below code.

Why is that I am getting the error? What Shall be done? My Python version is 3.8.11, Numpy (tried 1.20.1 and 1.18.5) and Keras is 2.4.3

```
from keras import models
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN

## I did try keras through Tensorflow as well using the below 2 lines
#from keras import models
#from keras.layers import SimpleRNN

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(SimpleRNN(units=32, input_shape=(1,4), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.summary()
```

Error:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20332/867103070.py in <module>
      3 
      4 model = models.Sequential()
----> 5 model.add(SimpleRNN(units=32, input_shape=(1,4), activation="relu"))
      6 model.add(Dense(1))
      7 model.summary()
-------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (simple_rnn_6/strided_slice:0) to a numpy array. This error may indicate that you're trying to pass a Tensor to a NumPy call, which is not supported
```

Comment: The error mostly occurred because of some issue with the way you are feeding data to the network. Add code related to that to your description.

Comment: Your code should work perfectly fine. You are missing at least the `Dense` import so I suspect the code snippet isn't complete ..

Comment: I did not feed the data yet. What ever is shown here is all the code. I just ran the model.summary() after creating the model, which shall output model layers, inputs, outputs and parameters. Instead it is throwing the error.

Comment: You should include the complete traceback, not just one line of it.

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question twice? [Getting NotImplementedError when trying Keras SimpleRNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69461477/getting-notimplementederror-when-trying-keras-simplernn)

Comment: @kubatucka. yes I did. When I tried to raise an issue at github.com/keras-team/keras/issues (suggested by you), it in turn suggested me this page to raise the question. Hence the duplication. Apologies.